# How to iterate a list and conditionally render its members?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a list of questions and they have statistics based on user answers.

Statistics for each question are rendered conditionally depending on question type:

- If question type is multiple choice then a pie chart should be
  rendered.
- If question type is text input then a data table should be rendered.

**Question.java**

```
private int type;

@Transient
private PieChartModel pieChart;

@Transient
private List<String> dataTable;
```

After calculating statistics I assign pieChart or dataTable. 
And I tried this to render them:

**Statistics.xhtml**

```
<ui:repeat var="question" value="#{bean.questions}">

            <p:chart rendered="#{question.type eq 1}" type="pie" model="#{question.pieChart}" />

            <p:dataTable rendered="#{question.type eq 2}" var="answer" value="question.dataTable">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="answer" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </ui:repeat>
```

It seem obvious that it is not possible to conditionally render child components of ui:repeat. Any way to do this?

Comment: You have a typo `value="question.dataTable"` should be `value="#{question.dataTable}"`. Apart from that are you sure that your bean name is `bean` and not `question` (as the bean is `Question.java`, you could get confused)?

Comment: Use JSTL to dynamically build the view.

Comment: @MathieuCastets yes there's a typo thank you. Yes it is bean, question is my model class.

Comment: As mentioned by @BalusC please try with `c:forEach' and `c:if` please